# Integral of function in $R^2$ - Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to solve this exercice:

Find all possible values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\min(|x|^\alpha,1)$ is in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$.

First I control if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.
So I want to calculate or estimate ( I guess the answer is estimate)

$||f||_2^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(x)| dx$

but I cannot do the integral because I don't know how to consider that $\min$.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha \ge 0$ then $|x|^\alpha \le 1$ if and only if $|x| \le 1$, and you can write $f$ as
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} |x|^\alpha & |x| \le 1 \\ 1 & |x| > 1. \end{array} \right.$$
If $\alpha < 0$ then $|x|^\alpha \ge 1$ if and only if $|x| \le 1$, and you can write $f$ as
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & |x| \le 1 \\ |x|^\alpha & |x| > 1. \end{array} \right.$$

In both cases you have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x)|^2 \, dx = \int_{|x| \le 1} |f(x)|^2 \, dx + \int_{|x| > 1} |f(x)|^2 \, dx$$ and you can evaluate the integrals individually.

Comment: Thank you! So, if $\alpha>=0$ I have $ \int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x)|^2 \, dx = \int_{|x| \le 1} |x|^{2\alpha} \, dx + \int_{|x| > 1} 1 \, dx $, and the second integral is $+\infty$ so $f$ isn't in $L^2$. Right?